# How can I use for loop to newline the table and clear the data?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I want to use `forloop` to new line the data (not in a row) and when I click the button, clear the last data (but remain the original title--id.lat.lng.speed.rpm.angle.state.time).
Extra, I found at the row back  2 fields aren't have any data. (WHY? Can I remove it?)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" import="java.io.*" import="java.util.*" import="java.sql.*"%> 
<html>
<head>
<script>
function click_x(clicked_id){
var xxx=[];
    xxx[0] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    xxx[1] = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    xxx[2] = [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
    xxx[3] = [24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
    xxx[4] = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39];
    xxx[5] = [40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47];

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
    var markersControlArray = [true,true,true,false,false];

    for(var k = 0 ; k < markersControlArray.length ; k++){
        if(markersControlArray[k] == true){
            for(var i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
                cell1 = row1.insertCell(i);
                cell1.innerHTML = xxx[k][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" border="3">
                <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Lat</th>
                 <th>Lng</th>
                 <th>Speed</th>
                 <th>Rpm</th>
                 <th>Angle</th>
                 <th>State</th>
                 <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
</table><br>
<button id="1" onClick="click_x(this.id)">Submit</button>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could be more precise on what your trying to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: I also want to clear the last data when click the button?(not piled the data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to insert new row in a table for each `xxx[k]` with `insertRow` method. You should do it at the beginning of the outer for loop. So the loops should look something like that:

```
for(var k = 0 ; k < markersControlArray.length ; k++){
    if(markersControlArray[k] == true){
        var row1 = table.insertRow(-1);
        for(var i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
            var cell1 = row1.insertCell(i);
            cell1.innerHTML = xxx[k][i];
        }
    }
}
```

Those empty cells are there because you create them before the loops, with this code:

```
var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);
```

Whole JavaScript code:

```
function click_x(clicked_id){
var xxx=[];
    xxx[0] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    xxx[1] = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    xxx[2] = [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
    xxx[3] = [24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
    xxx[4] = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39];
    xxx[5] = [40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47];

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var markersControlArray = [true,true,true,false,false,true]; // you have missed value for xxx[5] - I added it

    for(var k = 0 ; k < markersControlArray.length ; k++){
        if(markersControlArray[k] == true){
            var row1 = table.insertRow(-1);
            for(var i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
                var cell1 = row1.insertCell(i);
                cell1.innerHTML = xxx[k][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeDLq/4/).

In general I see that you have used code from some tutorial and didn't analyze it well enough and didn't remove unneeded code.

Comment: Can you also clear the last data when click the button?(not piled the data)

Comment: Can I use document.getElementById('myTable').deleteRow(); ?

Comment: @user3077712 Yes, you can. To remove rows with this method you have to make a call `document.getElementById('myTable').deleteRow(-1);` in the loop at the begining of your function to remove all rows except the first one (the one with headers). To check how much rows are in the table use `document.getElementById('myTable').rows.length` or `table.rows.length`, as you have this table in your `table` variable already.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function arrRow(tableId){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);    
    return row;
}

function click_x(clicked_id){
var xxx=[];
    xxx[0] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    xxx[1] = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
    xxx[2] = [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23];
    xxx[3] = [24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
    xxx[4] = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39];
    xxx[5] = [40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47];

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var markersControlArray = [true,true,true,false,false];

    for(var k = 0 ; k < markersControlArray.length ; k++){
        if(markersControlArray[k] == true){
            var RowVar = arrRow("myTable");
            for(var i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
                cell1 = RowVar.insertCell(i);
                cell1.innerHTML = xxx[k][i];
            }

        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" border="3">
                <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Lat</th>
                 <th>Lng</th>
                 <th>Speed</th>
                 <th>Rpm</th>
                 <th>Angle</th>
                 <th>State</th>
                 <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
</table><br>
<button id="1" onClick="click_x(this.id)">Submit</button>   
</body>
</html>
```